# Problems in google sheets COUNTIFS, for counting dates in range

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Im a google sheets newbie, im starting to try some advanced things and heres is the problem:

I have one spreadsheet with a list of all my agency clients, (actives, outs, and to be started). in this spreadsheet i have tree columns with dates: date of sale, date of project beginning, and date of left (if client ended the project) like these: [print of spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hepeb.png)

in another speadsheet i have a monthly data follow up.

So here its what i trying to do: Count how many active clientes i had active in the past specific months, (january, feb, march...) based on the date of beginning, and date of left, any idea how to do it?

i tryied this so far, it worked in some cases: -' `=ARRAYFORMULA(CONT.SES('Clientes Atual (Mensal)'!L:L;"<>";'Clientes Atual (Mensal)'!L:L;"<=30/08/2021")) - ARRAYFORMULA(CONT.SES('Clientes Atual (Mensal)'!M:M;"<>";'Clientes Atual (Mensal)'!M:M;"<=30/08/2021"))`

in this case calculating clients actives in august
where L:L is column of beginning date, and M:M column of leaving date

[Sheet link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15VSG75NqiqipGJQCZ0lQQdOKT9qceaH1VZ6zU9yTgwM/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

You could try a CountIF ... something like this:

[image]

Then just have a formula that identifies clients without end dates, or whatever the criteria happen to be.